# Possibilities of getting the visas processed on time

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, application-status

My husband and I are indian citizens and have planned to leave for Sweden on the 10th july 2015. We have submitted our visa application on the 24th June 2015. What are the possibilities of getting our visas processed before the scheduled date of travel?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT! Also, which embassy did you apply to?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but very tight. It's also possible that your application will take longer, either because there is something about it that requires extra verifications or simply because it's the holiday period.

The [Migration Agency](http://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Visiting-Sweden/Tourists-visas.html) (the authority responsible for this in Sweden) aims for a two-week turnaround time but obviously warns that it can take longer. While some other countries are not very responsive to this type of queries, the website also indicates that the consulate/embassy should be able to provide current information on processing times so you might be able to get a direct answer by contacting them.